# Should we write unit tests for the automation tests code base?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automation, automated-tests

Recently I was working in a team, who were writing the unit tests for the tests automation code base which was surprising to me. Do we even need that? If someone's answer is yes, then what about the unit tests for the unit tests and so on?

Comment: It's unclear what the context is. If they were creating their own testing framework, testing that it works correctly makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think @jonrsharpe hit the nail on the head.

Second, this might not be a good SO question since it's more opinion based. However, I find it to be a good question to reflect on, so I'll throw my opinion in.

Finally, to the point and put broadly, anytime you write code to **functionally** support a project that is **sufficiently complex**, it is worthwhile to test it to ensure it behaves. Whether that's supporting the function, delivery or monitoring of your particular project, it's all fair game to test.

To your question of the recursive test problem, the test code itself doesn't functionally support a project (i.e. if it disappeared, you would still be delivering functional software), so you don't need to write code to test your test code. Also, test code should aim to be fairly straightforward so if you find yourself writing sufficiently complex test code, you have a different problem!